# Groovy / java constant in Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

Is there anyway to refer to a java / groovy constant within dataweave. For example if I have a http.query.params name defined in a constants file can I grab it from a java file?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a java component.

[image]

And in your class, implement Callable and return the value you want.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem worth the hassle